# How to add OpenIdConnect via IdentityServer4 to ASP.NET Core ServerSide Blazor web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I did the following (It should work but it does not), no redirect, no error, no nothing, it just displays the page without auth, what am I doing wrong?

---

## **ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor**

**Step 1.** Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

**Step 2.** Edit Statup.cs

Under "ConfigurationServices" add

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
           options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //false for development only
           options.ClientId = "mywebclient";
           options.ResponseType = "code";
           options.UsePkce = true;
           options.Scope.Add("profile");
           options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
           options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

Under "Configure" add

```
        ...
        services.AddAuthorization();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();


        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        ....
```

**Step 3.** Add attribute Authorize to blazor page

```
        @page "/item"
        @attribute [Authorize]
```

Comment: Now there is a lot of official documentation available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code suffers from a couple of maladies... The main issue is that your code provides no authentication challenge request mechanism that enables redirection to an authenticating agent such as IdentityServer. This is only possible with HttpContext, which is not available in SignalR (Blazor Server App). To solve this issue we'll add a couple of Razor pages where the HttpContext is available. More in the answer...

The following is a complete and working solution to the question:

1. Create a Blazor Server App.
2. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect -Version 3.1.0
3. Create a component named LoginDisplay (LoginDisplay.razor), and place it in the Shared folder. This component is used in the MainLayout component

   `<AuthorizeView>
       <Authorized>
           <a href="logout">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name !</a>
           <form method="get" action="logout">
               <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
           </form>
       </Authorized>
       <NotAuthorized>
           <a href="login?redirectUri=/">Log in</a>
       </NotAuthorized>
   </AuthorizeView>`

   Add the LoginDisplay component to the MainLayout component, just above the About
   anchor element, like this

   `<div class="top-row px-4">
       <LoginDisplay />
       <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
   </div>`

Note: In order to redirect requests for login and for logout to IdentityServer, we have to create two Razor pages as follows:
1. Create a Login Razor page Login.cshtml (Login.cshtml.cs) and place them in the Pages folder as follow:

### Login.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
 using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new 
            AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri } );
    }  
}
```

This code starts the challenge for the Open Id Connect authentication scheme you defined in the Startup class.

2. Create a Logout Razor page Logout.cshtml (Logout.cshtml.cs) and place them in the Pages folder as well:

   ### Logout.cshtml.cs

   `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;`

   `public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
       {
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
           return Redirect("/");
       }
   }`

This code signs you out, redirecting you to the Home page of your Blazor app.

Replace the code in App.razor with the following code:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @{
                    var returnUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);

                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);

                }

            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                Wait...
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>

        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>

    </NotFound>

</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Replace the code in the Startup class with the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization; 
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = 
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = 
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = 
               OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
         {
             options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
             options.ClientId = "interactive.confidential.short"; 
             options.ClientSecret = "secret";
             options.ResponseType = "code";
             options.SaveTokens = true;
             options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
             options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
             options.Scope.Add("openid");
             options.Scope.Add("profile");
             options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
                    TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name"
                    };

             options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
             {
               OnAccessDenied = context =>
                        {
                          context.HandleResponse();
                          context.Response.Redirect("/");
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                       }
       };
 });

}


  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure 
     the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: in all the code sample above you'll have to add using statements as necessary. Most of them are provided by default. The using provided here are those necessary to enable the authentication and authorization flow.

- Run your app, click on the log in button to authenticate. You are being redirected to IdentityServer test server which allows you to perform an OIDC login. You may enter a user name: *bob* and password *bob*, and after click the OK button, you'll be redirected to your home page. Note also that you can use the external login provider Google (try it). Note that after you've logged in with identity server, the LoginDisplay component displays the string "Hello, ".

Note: While you're experimenting with your app, you should clear the browsing data, if you want to be redirected to the identity server's login page, otherwise, your browser may use the cached data. Remember, this is a cookie-based authorization mechanism...

Note that creating a login mechanism as is done here does not make your app more secured than before. Any user can access your web resources without needing to log in at all. In order to secure parts of your web site, you have to implement authorization as well, conventionally, an authenticated user is authorized to access secured resource, unless other measures are implemented, such as roles, policies, etc. The following is a demonstration how you can secure your Fetchdata page from unauthorized users (again, authenticated user is considered authorized to access the Fetchdata page).

1. At the top of the Fetchdata component page add the @attribute directive for the Authorize attribute, like this: `@attribute [Authorize]`
   When an unauthenticated user tries to access the Fetchdata page, the `AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized` delegate property is executed, so we can add some code to redirect the user to the same identity server's login page to authenticate.
2. The code within the NotAuthorized element looks like this:

   `<NotAuthorized>
       @{
           var returnUrl = 
           NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
           NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?redirectUri= 
                                 {returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
        }
   </NotAuthorized>`

This retrieves the url of the last page you were trying to access, the Fetchdata page, and then navigates to the Login Razor page from which a password challenge is performed, that is, the user is redirected to the identity server's login page to authenticate.

After the user has authenticated he's redirected to the Fetchdata page.

Good luck...

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed response and full set of instructions :) you win!

Comment: how would you handle access token expiration?

Comment: This is a little bit problematic as Signalr has no concept of HttpContext and cookies. I'll try to find out a solution  for this, and let you know about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official support yet for IdentityServer and OIDC flow in Blazor. I already [opened](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17256) [several](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18066) [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12601) on the aspnetcore github but they always got closed without a proper answer.

The best sources I found for the moment are the following blogs:

https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/15/blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect.html

https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-httpclientfactory-and-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

> it just displays the page without auth, what am I doing wrong

It's likely you didn't add a AuthorizeRouteView for your app. Note that `@attribute [Authorize]` is only a directive that adds a `[AuthorizeAttribute]` for that page component. To enable the authorization for route, you need to :

1. Add a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` at a very top level
2. Add a `<AuthorizeRouteView>` to enable the authorization for route. See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component)
3. Use `<AuthorizeView>` for plain component authorization. Add a `<NotAuthorized>` to display the component when not authorized. And use `Authorizing` to display component while authorizing user. See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component)

For example, you `BlazorApp.razor` might look like:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
                <NotAuthorized>
                    You're not allowed!
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <h1>Authentication in progress</h1>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```