# How do I get the access token from a blazor (server-side) web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

After implementing openidconnect, where does blazor store the access token? how to retrieve it?

---

[How to add OpenIdConnect via IdentityServer4 to ASP.NET Core ServerSide Blazor web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638965/how-to-add-openidconnect-via-identityserver4-to-asp-net-core-serverside-blazor-w)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component

Comment: I'm still trying to come up with a solution for "how would you handle access token expiration?" It's immensely difficult... I'll answer your current question soon... Incidentally, what do you want the access token for ?

Comment: I want to exchange the id token for a (client credential) access token (If I can not figure this out, I would have to do it in a different)

Comment: I can still recommend this blog: https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/15/blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect.html.

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding the code from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/quick-start-blazor-server-app#make-a-call-to-the-web-api

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code snippets provide a way to retrieve the access token issued when a user is authenticated with IdentityServer4 provider. In order to get the 
access token you can use the HttpContext object, but since Blazor is SignalR-based, you'll have to do it the only time the HttpContext object is available, when the connection to your application is an HTTP connection, and not a WebSocket connection.

After retrieving the access token, you need to pass it to your Blazor app, and store it in a local storage. My code also provide a way to parse the access token, if necessary.

- Add a file to the Pages folder and name it _Host.cshtml.cs
- Add this code to the file:

  ```
   public class HostAuthenticationModel : PageModel
   {
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
       {
           if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
              var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
              AccessToken = token;

           }
      return Page();
   }

   public string AccessToken { get; set; }
   }
  ```

Note: I've name the the PageModel class: HostAuthenticationModel
You'll need some of these:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;`

- Next we have to pass the value stored in the AccessToken property to the Blazor App:

In the _Host.cshtml file add the model directive at the top portion of the file:

```
@model HostAuthenticationModel
```

Add a new attribute to the component Tag Helper like this:

```
param-AccessToken="Model.AccessToken"
```

Final result:

```
 <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" 
                 param-AccessToken="Model.AccessToken"/>
 </app>
```

The `param-AccessToken` attribute requires you to define a property named *AccessToken* in the *App component* which will get the access token from the page model.

- Next define the property which will receive the access token
- And then override the OnAfterRenderAsync method from which we call a method to
  store the access token in the local storage.

  ```
  @code{
     [Parameter]
     public string AccessToken { get; set; }

     protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
     {
         if (firstRender)
          {
              await tokenStorage.SetTokenAsync(AccessToken);
          }
     }
   }
  ```

Also place the following at the top of the App component:

```
@inject AccessTokenStorage tokenStorage
```

- Next you'll have to create the AccessTokenStorage service like this:

  Create a class named *AccessTokenStorage* at the root of your app, and add the 
  following code:

  public class AccessTokenStorage
  {
      private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

  ```
  public AccessTokenStorage(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
  {
      _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
  }

  public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
      => await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "accessToken");

  public async Task SetTokenAsync(string token)
  {
      if (token == null)
      {
          await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.removeItem", 
                                                          "accessToken");
      }
      else
      {
          await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.setItem", 
                                                 "accessToken", token);
      }


   }
  }
  ```

I guess no explanation is needed here... Here's some using directives you may need

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;`

Add the following to the Startup.ConfigureServices

`services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddScoped<AccessTokenStorage>();`

Note: the above code should be used with the code I provide  [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638965/how-to-add-openidconnect-via-identityserver4-to-asp-net-core-serverside-blazor-w)

Comment: I'm still working on a solution for "how would you handle access token expiration?" . Please post a question for this in a couple of days.

Comment: wow, great work! by the way, are you doing all this to answer the question only or you also need to retrieve the access token for your own app?

Comment: Glad to be of help!... I'm doing it as part of my learning Blazor. Personally, I do not need it, but I augment my knowledge by solving a plethora of questions here. Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Tested it, it works! however where did you get to use this? services.AddHttpClient();

Comment: why not just store the token via OnGet in _host.cshtml.cs?

Comment: store it where ? My code passes the access token to my Blazor Server App from which it is stored in a JavaScript local storage, and retrieved as necessary.

Comment: When you use Blazor Server App it is recommended to use  IHttpClientFactory...IHttpClientFactory can be registered by calling AddHttpClient...See basic usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#basic-usage

Comment: Yes however, I don't see where httpclient is required.

Comment: I'm sorry... yes, httpclient is not required here. In my app, however, I use it to test http calls to a web api. Just delete it...

Comment: @enet https://stackoverflow.com/q/66325590/4337436 Could you please assist me here?

Answer (score 12):

I resolved this issue by adding the code listed in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/quick-start-blazor-server-app#prepare-the-app-to-use-azure-ad-tokens

**Note:** The steps listed in the link above work fine, however, I made some small modifications that make more sense to me.  I also modified the order that make more sense to me.

**Steps:**

**1. Create the TokenProvider class**

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Update the _Host.cshtml file with the following:**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

@{
   
    var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
}

<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" param-AccessToken="accessToken" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>
```

**3. Update StartUp.cs with DI:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
```

**4. Update App.razor with the following:**

```
@inject TokenProvider TokenProvider

@code
{
    
    [Parameter]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //Accept the parameter from _Host.cshtml and move into the Token Provider 
        TokenProvider.AccessToken = AccessToken;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

**5. Create an instance of the _tokenProvider in the constructor**
**and use it to get the Access Token**

**Note:** Below I get the access token NOT in the @code block or the code behind of the Blazor page, but I am using a Service class. (The page calls the Service class). I hope this makes sense.  Again, I would suggest reviewing the link above.

```
    private readonly TokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    //Create tokenProvider using constructor Dependency Injection
    public HttpClientUtility(TokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

var accessToken = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;

if (accessToken != null)
{
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
}
```

Hopefully the above steps will help someone else.

Comment: The provided link is the official way, it's fairly simple and should be the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @Richard I have followed your steps.. and I am struck in step 5 which you mentioned `_tokenProvider` from constructor DI. Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: @Richard https://stackoverflow.com/q/66325590/4337436 I have raised my question here. If you can please assist me.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu Sorry I didn't get this till recently. Reviewing your post above it looks as though you got though it.

Comment: @Richard I always receive `null` value when accessing `TokenProvider`. Please assist on this.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu When you say TokenProvider receives null. Do you mean TokenProvider is null or AccessToken it returns is null?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu You asked me to elaborate on Step 5 and the _tokenProvider. I don't really understand what you are asking but I will try my best. In Step 3 the DI (Dependence Injection) was set up.  So, in Step 5 you would create an instance of the _tokenProvider in the constructor of the class which you need to us it in.  If I can, I will edit the code example above.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu I added more detail to Step 5. I hope it helps.  Again review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/quick-start-blazor-server-app#prepare-the-app-to-use-azure-ad-tokens

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Just one thing: in .AddOpenIdConnect you must set   options.SaveTokens = true;  otherwise it won't work. I searched a long time for this detail. I think, this was also the problem from  
Balagurunathan

Answer (score 1):

I used the following way

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

**Razor page**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor


@code {    
    private async Task<string> GetToken()
            => await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
}
```

Comment: Why the -1? Lack of explanation? Doesn't work? Bad practice?

Comment: -1 because of 2 reasons.  1. This didn't work for me.  My OnPrem solution had the above code and it worked. However, when I deployed to Azure, this solution did not work. Above is a detailed post with how I got it to work in Azure. 2. I have read numerous post that stated getting the access token from the HttpContextAccessor / HttpContext is not a good practice.

Comment: I think that it is not safe to read HttpContext this way inside blazor page, because it runs on a "Circuit" and the Context might not be the Context that is pertinent to the actual Circuit.