# Blazor serverside + Cognito Logout?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, amazon-cognito, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm kinda new to blazor and I'm having issues with logging users out of the application. I've looked at various documents and tutorials but I haven't found anything mentioning logging out. I've tried calling the Cognito logout endpoint (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) but my application still sees the user as authenticated. I also tried getting the access_token using the answer in this thread [How do I get the access token from a blazor (server-side) web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app) but it always returns null for me. The isAuthenticated property always return true regardless of what I do. Anyone got any ideas?

In startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout";

                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:MetadataAddress"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientSecret"];
            });
```

In LoginDisplay.razor

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
    identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var isAuthenticated = identity.IsAuthenticated;
    
    email = identity!.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")?.Value ?? string.Empty;
    var userData = await userService.GetUserByEmail(email.ToLower());
    userData.Then(u =>
        userRole = u.Role
        , () =>
            userRole = UserRole.Anonymous
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's document [AuthenticationStateProvider service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authenticationstateprovider-service), we should not use AuthenticationStateProvider directly since it does not automatically notified of authentication state data changes.

Use AuthrizedView and CascadingStateProvider components instead.