# Retrieve Azure AD token on Blazor Server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, token, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app where I managed to get the authentication with Azure AD to work, but I am unable to retrieve the Azure AD token. I have the following:

_Host.cshtml:

```
@{
Layout = null;


var tokens = new InitialApplicationState
{
    AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
    RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
};
}

<component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState="tokens" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Add("User.Read");
});
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
```

TokenProvider.cs:

```
public class TokenProvider
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

InitialApplicationState.cs:

```
public class InitialApplicationState
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

GradingApiService.cs:

```
public class GradingApiService : IGradingApiService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly TokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public GradingApiService(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration, TokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public async Task<Gradings> GetRiskAppetiteGradingByQuoteID()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                "https://grading-api-func-uks-tst.azurewebsites.net/api/Gradings/a0999a23-b275-4993-a959-6185cd769c0a");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Gradings>();
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Gradings();
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I retrieve the token I obtain a null value. Could you help me to understand what's wrong with this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if references can be worked around and check if you have missed any configuration:

Make sure you check mark access token and  id token

[image]

Try to Add client secret if you call api (only if needed)

[image]

If you can initialize component in app.razor page

In app.razor component

```
@using BlazorserverDemoApp.Data
@inject TokenProvider TokensProvider 


<CascadingAuthenticationState>
…
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code{
    [Parameter]
 public InitialApplicationState InitialState { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TokensProvider.AccessToken = InitialState.AccessToken;
        TokensProvider.RefreshToken = InitialState.RefreshToken;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

please include  services.AddRazorPages(); if it is made use before          services.AddScoped();

**Add the scope of your api**, `usually User.Read is the graph endpoint` , so  provide your scope given in portal for your api here. And  add  endpoints.MapControllers();

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("<<scope>>");      //add the scope of your api 
                options.Resource = "<<resource>>";
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();                   //add this
            services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();;

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();             //this is important
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();   
            services.AddTransient<WeatherForecastService>();
    
  
    }
```

In configure method in startup.cs

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
           // endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapControllers(); //add this
                    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                });
```

Please See if you are missing  tag

```
     <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState="tokens" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
     </app>
```

On the api `service side api` or In fetch.razor, hope you had made use of `IhttpClientFactory`

```
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly TokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public GradingApiService(IhttpClientFactory httpClient, IConfiguration configuration, TokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient.CreateClient();
        _configuration = configuration;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

public HttpClient _httpClient { get; }

public async Task<Gradings> GetRiskAppetiteGradingByQuoteID()
    {

        Try
          { 
           var token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;
            
           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "your/api"); 

               request.Headers. Authorization=new 
             System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(“Bearer”, token);
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

             return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Gradings>();

               }
             Catch
                  {
                   //code..
                 }
         }
```

**References:**

1. [Quickstart| Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/quick-start-blazor-server-app#prepare-the-app-to-use-azure-ad-tokens)
2. [blazor-server-aad-sample(github.com)](https://github.com/javiercn/blazor-server-aad-sample/tree/master/BlazorServerAuthWithAzureActiveDirectory)
3. [how-do-i-get-the-access-token | stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app)