# Blazor authentication with OpenId: call HttpClient with JWT token

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

In my Blazor Web Assembly project with `.NET6`, I have the authentication with Identity Server (OpenId). In the `Program.cs` I read the configuration from the `app.settings` with

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
})
.AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<MultipleRoleClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>();
```

Also, I use `HttpClient` to call an API and retrieve data.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiEndpoint) });
```

Now, the point is that I want to use the user token to call the API. I tried different functions like `AuthenticationService` but there is not a method to read the token. I tried to use `AuthenticationStateProvider` but again nothing.

I saw this [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app) but it is not my case because I have a WebAssembly.